# Import/Copy metadata from template to multiple raster datasets in file geodatabase with ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, metadata

I have a file geodatabase with multiple DEM (raster datasets) and any of them should be imported metadata. I created a template metadata file with extension *.xml and tried to do it but not imported.

That is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import metadata as md

# Set the standard-format metadata XML file's path
src_file_path = "C:\Thinned_test\\templete_test.xml"

# Get the target item's Metadata object
trees_path = "C:\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test.gdb
tgt_item_md = md.Metadata(trees_path)

# Import the standard-format metadata content to the target item
if  tgt_item_md.isReadOnly:
    tgt_item_md.importMetadata(src_file_path)
    tgt_item_md.save()
```

**UPDATE**

I did research about `ListRaster()` and tried to import for all of my rasters but maybe need to put something after variable `rasterList`.

That is my code:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import metadata as md

# Set the standard-format metadata XML file's path
src_file_path = "C:\\Thinned_test\\templete_test.xml"

# Get the target item's Metadata object
arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test.gdb"
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
tgt_item_md = md.Metadata(rasterList)
for rasterList in rasterList:

# Import the standard-format metadata content to the target item
 if not tgt_item_md.isReadOnly:
     tgt_item_md.importMetadata(src_file_path)
     tgt_item_md.save()
```

Any idea why not imported?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is flawed, you ask if the metadata is Read Only, well if it is read only you can't write to it!

You probably wanted to say:

```py
if not tgt_item_md.isReadOnly:
   tgt_item_md.importMetadata(src_file_path)
   tgt_item_md.save()
```

A way of example if I type this into the python console I get False which means I can write to it.

```py
p = r"C:\Temp\test.gdb\fcTest"
from arcpy import metadata as md
tgt_item_md = md.Metadata(p)
tgt_item_md.isReadOnly
False
```

**Update:**

In your now amended code, using the ListRaster() to step over rasters is the correct way of looping over rasters in a workspace, currently your code is incorrect as you are not actually looping over the contents of the list, below is a corrected version for you to study:

```py
# Get the target item's Metadata object
arcpy.env.workspace ="C:\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test.gdb"
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for aRaster in rasterList:
    fullpathtoRaster = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + aRaster
    tgt_item_md = md.Metadata(fullpathtoRaster)
    # Import the standard-format metadata content to the target item
    if not tgt_item_md.isReadOnly:
         tgt_item_md.importMetadata(src_file_path)
         tgt_item_md.save()
```

Comment: I do it like you but the result is the same. The metadata in the raster datasets are empty.

Comment: @KDzha for variable `raster_path` is pointing to the GeoDatabase not a raster inside your GeoDatabase.

Comment: I am a beginner in arcpy and I think that enough to pointing the GeoDatabase, my rasters are inside it. What should be written to import the template for all rasters in the geodatabase? Could you please help me :)

Comment: You need a full path, so if your raster is say called  `lcm2020` then its full path would be "C:\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test\\METADATA_test.gdb\\lcm2020". Want to loop over many rasters in the geodatabase then search the help and study the code samples for ListRasters().

Comment: @KDzha don't place code in comments it is unreadable as indentation in python is important. EDIT your existing question, typically people put "update" then what ever it is they want to add.